# Using Property Placeholder for Bean ID

Tags: spring, spring-3, spring-integration

In Spring 3.1, is it possible to use a property placeholder to resolve the 'id' attribute of a bean?

I would like, for example, to do the following in my context.xml file:

```
<context:property-placeholder/>

<int:channel id="${channel.name}"/>
```

Comment: Is this still the case? It seems to be

Comment: Did you resolve this? I want to dynamically add channels and thus need to be able to specify their name. It seems to still be the case in Spring 4

Answer (score 2):

No, not for the id and the name attributes - this is based on what I have seen of how PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer resolves the placeholders.